# Can I rely on garbage collector to close asynchronous database connections in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, garbage-collection, connection-pooling

My team is working on an asynchronous HTTP web server implemented in Python (CPython 3.11 to be exact). We're using Redis for data storage and connect to it with the help of the [redis-py](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. Since the HTTP server is asynchronous, we use the `redis.asyncio.Redis` client class - it creates a connection pool internally and manages it automatically.

The Redis server is hosten in AWS, and will have password rotation configured. Currently, we're trying to come up with a way how to deal with this fact in our Python code automatically. There're 2 steps that we have to perform:

1. Create a new connection pool as soon as we know that new credentials are available
2. Close the existing connection pool as soon as we know that **it will not be used anymore**

The problem here is step #2. It's not guaranteed that we'll be able to introduce any synchronization mechanism that would tell us whether the connection pool can be safely closed manually (i.e. there're no HTTP requests being handled at that very moment which rely on the old connection pool), so we're looking for an alternative automated solution first. Right now I'd like to know whether we can rely on garbage collector to **safely** close any existing connections for us.

According to [the documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asyncio_examples.html#Connecting-and-Disconnecting), `redis.asyncio.Redis` instances must be closed manually because the `__del__` magic method, which is synchronous by its nature, cannot execute `await self.aclose()` itself. At the same time, I'm wondering what happens if these objects are simply destroyed by the GC. In theory, the cleanup process should go something like this:

1. GC destroys a `redis.asyncio.Redis` instance (a.k.a. client) together with all its fields
2. GC destroys the connection-pool-class instance stored inside that client
3. GC destroys the connection-list stored inside that connection pool
4. GC desroys all the connection-class instances stored inside that list

I performed an aritificial test similar to this:

```py
client = Redis(...)

await asyncio.gather(*(
    client.get(f"key_{i}") for i in range(100)
))

# checkpoint 1
client = Redis(...)
# checkpoint 2
```

And the Redis server reported 100 connections being open at checkpoint #1, and 0 connections being open at checkpoint #2 (in one case immediately, and in a slightly different case I had to make another request to the Redis server using the new client instance beforehand). It seems that (ab-)using the GC like this doesn't keep any connections hanging on the Redis server, but can we be sure that everything will be properly cleaned up on the HTTP server, and we won't end up with any memory leaks or hanging system resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: "Can I rely...?"

Yes.

---

There's two terms you keep using which we should carefully define.

Where you say "python", I choose to interpret that
as "the cPython 3.12 interpreter"
(or pretty much any modern 3.x interpreter).

Where you say "GC", I mostly view that as "ancient variable goes out-of-scope".

The "python language" encompasses several implementations,
including Jython and Iron Python.
Each implementation has its own approach to managing
and reclaiming memory allocations.

The cPython bytecode interpreter certainly does have a Garbage Collector.
But it is executed infrequently, for the special case of dealing
with cyclic datastructures. Usually
[reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)
is what's of interest. When an object's ref count goes to zero,
for example when it goes out of scope,
the cPython interpreter immediately reclaims its storage.
This is quite predictable synchronous behavior.
Very few python apps rely heavily on `__del__` methods
to reclaim resources, as `__del__` execution may
be deferred for a long time or even indefinitely.

In java we commonly see `x = null`,
to tell the GC that `x` is no longer needed
and it's open season on collecting the storage
of what it used to point to.
In python we *can* write `del x`,
but that is seldom useful.
If caller still holds a reference,
then decrementing *our* reference count
won't drive it to zero, so nothing happens.

The situation where explicit `del` tends to be
most useful is `del mydict[some_key]`,
to prevent a dictionary's storage from
growing without bound.

---

You are not abusing any GC facilities.

As long as async routines eventually `return`,
then yes, redis objects will be reclaimed
without memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're correct in your assumptions: w're using CPython 3.11, the Redis client instance is stored as an attribute of the application context and we're planning to simply overwrite it whenever we need to connect to Redis with the new credentials, and our HTTP request handling functions store a reference to the existing client in a local variable to keep that client reachable and prevent GC from claiming it.

Comment: If you “commonly see `x = null`” in Java, you are commonly looking at bad code. It’s rarely useful to write such a thing in Java, even less useful than using `del` in Python.