Can explicitly invoking the garbage collector in Python have side effects in this case?
can anyone help me with this?
When I call the heal_client method, and gc.collect() is executed, it successfully closes my database connection (just what I need). Is there something wrong with this approach, specifically with calling gc.collect() ?
(This code is part of a larger context involving asyncio and other libraries that got me to this point. It is expected that this method should almost never be called, but it has to be done because I have no other way to close the client and it is a long-running program.)
In conclusion, this approach seems to solve my problem, but I want to know if there might be a side effect that I am not seeing.
class RedisNotifier(INotifier):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__redis_client = redis.Redis(
        host=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_HOST,
        port=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PORT,
        password=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PASSWORD,
    )

    async def send_notification(self, room: str, notification: NotificationMessage) -> None:
        await self.__redis_client.publish(room, notification.json())

    def heal_client(self) -> None:
        print("Healing redis client")
        del self.__redis_client
        gc.collect()
        self.__redis_client = redis.Redis(
            host=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_HOST,
            port=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PORT,
            password=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PASSWORD,
        )
        print("done")


Since the runtime is free to invoke garbage collection at the same point you are explicitly doing so, I don't see how you calling it would be a problem.

Why do you think you need to call gc.collect()? If you're depending on that to close the redis connection, why not just call self.__redis_client.close()?

The problem is in the context. I can't call close because it's a point in the program where the event loop is already closed (and it is a long-running program), so I can't use those methods. (It's the Redis asynchronous client for Py). I found this too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77535074/can-i-rely-on-garbage-collector-to-close-asynchronous-database-connections-in-py

Sorry, I just saw that I didn't put the imports to clarify that it was the async client

well, yes, of course there could be side effects, just like the one you are relying on!
